# DIV to match width of TABLE

Tags: html, css

I have a container DIV. Inside the container are three elements. Two banner DIV's (simulating a header and footer) and a TABLE. The TABLE is enormously wide. There is no way to get around the horizontal scrolling and I must have the banners background color extend to match the full length of the DIV. How do I have the DIV expand its width to the entire width of the TABLE and why is the TABLE not affecting the width of its parent DIV?

thank you.

See my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yaksandpie/rqJQg/2/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Removing the `width: 100%` and adding `display: inline-block` to the container element should do it. http://jsfiddle.net/rqJQg/6/

Comment: Thank you very very much. Any idea why a block level element is not changing beyond the viewport because of a child element? Thank you again